# Mysql Filter Data by Range from Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a 'transfers' table that have 'amount' columns.. the structure of the 'transfers' table looks like this

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| id | from_account_id | to_account_id | date | amount |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

there are still more columns actually but these columns above is the most related with my question

now i have another table, let's say 'promo_dtl' table, that shows the current promos applied for transactions.. the table looks like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | promo_id | min_amount_trx | max_amount_trx | cashback_type | cashback_value | max_cashback_value |
```

now what i trying to do is, i want to query from 'transfers' table, filtering it by range of `min_amount_trx` and `max_amount_trx` from 'promo_dtl' table..

**Edited:**
for example, there are 2 records in 'promo_dtl' table, with the same `promo_id` value.. the first row has `min_amount_trx` 100 and `max_amount_trx` 1000.. and the second has `min_amount_trx` 5000 and `max_amount_trx` 10000

so i want to find records in transaction amount between 100 to 1000 and between 5000 to 10000

i tried this simple query

```
select * from transfers trf
where trf.amount 
    between (select min_amount_trx from promo_dtl where promo_id = 1)
    and  (select max_amount_trx from promo_dtl where promo_id = 1)
;
```

but this is what i got from above query

```
Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

So how can i get the data correctly? am i have to use join? if so, can anyone help me with this? thanks :D

Comment: Add some sample table data as well as the expected result - all as well formatted text (i.e no images or links.)

Comment: Error means that SubQuery should return 1 row, so if I understood what you mean, it looks like in the Subqueries you used, you have to `Select MIN(min_amount_trx)` and `Select MAX(max_amount_trx)`

Comment: you need to pass single row values to between query valeu . but your subquery retuning more than one row . so it's throwing error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Inner Join this way I think:

```
Select * from transfers
INNER JOIN promo_dtl 
on transfers.amount >= promo_dtl.min_amount_trx  
    AND dbo.transfers.amount <= promo_dtl.max_amount_trx 
    AND promo_id = 1
```

This should give you all the data you need.
I created a small sample to test and here's the result:

```
id          from_account_id to_account_id date                    amount
----------- --------------- ------------- ----------------------- -----------
1           1               2             2017-06-02 11:02:11.937 75
2           3               4             2017-06-02 11:02:21.950 300
3           5               6             2017-06-02 11:02:31.777 750

(3 row(s) affected)

id          promo_id    min_amount_trx amx_amount_trx
----------- ----------- -------------- --------------
1           1           50             100
2           1           500            1000
3           2           250            400

(3 row(s) affected)

id          from_account_id to_account_id date                    amount      id          promo_id    min_amount_trx amx_amount_trx
----------- --------------- ------------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------- --------------
1           1               2             2017-06-02 11:02:11.937 75          1           1           50             100
3           5               6             2017-06-02 11:02:31.777 750         2           1           500            1000
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that one of these:

```
select min_amount_trx from promo_dtl where promo_id = 1

select max_amount_trx from promo_dtl where promo_id = 1
```

Are returning more the one row. Which do not work. You could do like this:

```
select * from transfers trf
where trf.amount 
    between (select MIN(min_amount_trx) from promo_dtl where promo_id = 1)
    and  (select MAX(max_amount_trx) from promo_dtl where promo_id = 1)
;
```

You can aggregate the range using min and max

**Update:**

Even if it do not really make sense to me.
If you like to do what you are saying. You can try with and EXISTS. Like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    transfers
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM promo_dtl
    WHERE promo_dtl.promo_id=1
    AND transfers.amount 
        BETWEEN promo_dtl.min_amount_trx 
        AND promo_dtl.max_amount_trx 
);
```

Comment: if i using min() max(), how if there are 2 rows, first is min: 100 max: 500 and second is min: 1000 max: 5000.. so the query will find records between 100 and 5000.. which is unnecessary

Comment: But who should this be picked?

Comment: both of them.. so in above case, i want to find transactions between 100-500, and 1000-5000 :D

Comment: @thekucays Please update your question so we understand it better, I made the same mistake in my comment to the initial post.

Comment: @thekucays : Update the answer

Comment: @Arion your code works, but using inner join like paul's suggestion works faster.. thanks for your help btw dude :)